# Merge columns and generate new column based on the number in original column using EXCEL

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, merge, multiple-columns

I got an issue when trying to merge columns in Excel which should be common in real life but superisingly not found on internet(May be that's just because I didn't find it). The problem is here below:

Assume you have a table in sheet which have two columns, column A is the name for some items such as parks like Disney, Water Park, Universal Studio etc. and column B is the number that assigned to each item representing the serial number of this item. A sample table is like:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Disney | 2 |
| Water Park | 4 |

What i intend to do is create a new column, says Column C, where Disney 1 and Disney 2 are listed. And the new table is like:

| Column C |
| --- |
| Disney 1 |
| Disney 2 |
| Water Park 1 |
| Water Park 2 |
| Water Park 3 |
| Water Park 4 |

Does anyone know how to realize this conversion using Excel function?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted then the following formula should work which uses a `LAMBDA()` helper function called `MAKEARRAY()`*

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     α, A1:A2,
     φ, B1:B2,
     TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(α),MAX(φ),LAMBDA(δ,ε,
     IF(ε<=INDEX(φ,δ),INDEX(α,δ)&" "&ε,p))),3))
```

---

Here is another alternative method without using any `LAMBDA()` helper functions:

[image]

---

```
=LET(α, SEQUENCE(,MAX(B1:B2)), TOCOL(IF(α>B1:B2,0/0,A1:A2&" "&α),3))
```

---

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)` and what I see it will be easier & simpler to achieve using the said tool.

[image]

---

---

To use Power Query follow the steps: (Read the steps annotations to follow)

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_ONE`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_ONE"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each {1..[Column2]}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom", {{"Custom", type text}}, "en-US"),{"Column1", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Output"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"Column2"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Comment: Hi Mayukh, thanks a lot! I followed steps you just shared above and it did work out! This is so helpful!